# How to align multi-line text after icon

Tags: html, css

In a table with indentation (tree data), i need to align second line with the first line.

Notice, text "Tail" doesn't align with "Long"

[image]

Created a similar example here

```css
div{
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="">ICon:</a>
  <span>This is my fight song. Take back my life song. Prove I'm alright song. My power's turned on
Starting right now I'll be strong</span>    
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need a slightly more complex HTML structure. Are you free to change it?

Comment: The rendered demo and the image show the same issue--the wrapped text falls under the icon. I suspect that Khan wants something like a table layout.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`

```css
div{
  width:400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
}

a, span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="">ICon:</a>
  <span>This is my fight song. Take back my life song. Prove I'm alright song. My power's turned on
Starting right now I'll be strong</span>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap, you can do it using rows and cols like below :

```html
<div className="text-wrap row">
  <div className="col-1 ">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheckCircle} size="lg" />
  </div>
  <div className="col-11">This Is my fight Song This Is my fight Song This Is my fight Song This Is my fight Song This Is my fight Song This Is my fight Song This Is my fight Song This Is my fight Song This Is my fight Song</div>
</div>
```