# Content inside of flexbox container not displaying links inline

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I'm fairly new to flexbox but can't seem to find an answer on here for this. I have a `<p>` tag which I've made into a flex container, and within the `<p>` I would like to insert a link inline with the text.

**Required result:**

[image: Required result]

**However the result I'm getting is this:**

[image: Current result]

The only way I can get the intended result is to change the display property of the `<a>` tag to 'contents', however a quick look on CanIUse show's that IE doesn't support it, and I need it to for this task.

I also don't want to restructure the HTML as this is to be rendered in a WYSIWYG, and simply adding classes to the `<p>` tag would be the best scenario.

I've made a [pen of the issue here](https://codepen.io/paddyfields/pen/zyvVLy), with the scss version, and the compiled code is also posted below. Any help would be great.

```css
.my-alert {
    width: 500px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 900 !important;
}

.my-alert:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-size: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-weight: 900 !important;
}

.my-alert-success {
    color: green;
    border-color: green;
}

.my-alert-success:before {
  content: '\f058'
}
```

```html
<p class="my-alert my-alert-success">Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident culpa.<a href="/">Here is my link.</a> And here is more content.</p>
```

Comment: never use flexbox as container of text ... this said, what you want to achieve at the end? alignment?

Comment: The reasoning is so that the icon on the left will be vertically aligned regardless of the height of the box (as the text length can very)

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34820741/8620333 ... this what you need, simply replace `vertical-align:top` with middle

Comment: That looks ideal, thanks. Other than the obvious example that my problem doesn't need flexbox as a solution, when you say 'never use flexbox as a container for text', is there a more specific reason? Just for future reference.

Comment: the reason is exactly the issue you are facing. using flexbox with text will make your text behave like flex items (similar to block level) and you will break the normal flow of text (inline element). Flexbox is for layout considering different block that should be separate, not for simple text.Flexbox is good but it should not be an automatic solution for everything

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `display:flex` here, because it will treat all the elements inside its container as 'blocks'.

```css
.my-alert {
    width: 500px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    /*display: flex; */
    padding-left:40px;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 900 !important;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    &:before {
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
        font-size: 40px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding-right: 20px;
        font-weight: 900 !important;
      position:absolute; 
      left:8px; 
      top:50%;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
}

.my-alert-success {
    color: green;
    border-color: green;
    &:before {
        content: '\f058';
    }
}
```